# nest multiple values in yaml array

Tags: yaml

I need to turn this section of a yaml file into an array:

```
  - name: postgresql_service_node
    release: cf-services-contrib
    template: postgresql_node_ng
    instances: 1
    resource_pool: common
    persistent_disk: 10000
    properties:
      postgresql_node:
        plan: default
    networks:
      - name: default
        default: [dns, gateway]
```

I'm having a specific problem with this part:

```
properties:
  postgresql_node:
    plan: default
networks:
  - name: default
    default: [dns, gateway]
```

In getting it to be an array.

This is as far as I've got:

```
templates: {    
    name: postgresql_service_node,
    release: cf-services-contrib,
    template: postgresql_node_ng,
    instances: 1,
    resource_pool: common,
    persistent_disk: 10000,
    properties:
      postgresql_node:
        plan: default
    networks:
      - name: default
        default: [dns, gateway]
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR:

while parsing a flow mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 12:
    templates: {    
               ^
expected ',' or '}', but got ':'
  in "<unicode string>", line 9, column 22:
          postgresql_node:
                         ^
```

How can I state this correctly in yaml?

Comment: What do you mean by array? You seem to just be trying to create a hash that maps `templates` to another hash.

Comment: Your question is unclear. On a terminology note, YAML doesn't have arrays, it has sequences, which are ordered collections denoted by `-` in their block (multi-line) form or square braces in their flow (single line) form and which are deserialized to numerically-indexed arrays in most languages; and mappings, which are unordered collections that usually (but not necessarily) have scalar (string) keys and deserialize to hashes or hash maps in most languages (or "associative arrays" in PHP). What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: P.S. YAML mappings use curly braces in their flow (single line) form, but in their block form they use neither curly braces nor commas.